# select option by value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 4 options:

```
<input type="radio" name="tag" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="tag" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="tag" value="3"/>
<input type="radio" name="tag" value="4"/>
```

I have written a previous page function in jquery which returns the option already selected :

```
var option_selected = could be 1,2,3 or 4;

$('#previous').click(function (){

});
```

Please tell me how is that possible when I click this previous button the option already selected should be selected. What should I add in this function to do so?

Comment: How are you storing the previously selected value?

Comment: It is stored in database which is retrived by ajax call in variable "option_selected"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input:radio[name="tag"][value="' + option_selected + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Read about **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)**

#### A little explanation:

`$('input:radio[name="tag"][value="' + option_selected + '"]')` select the `input[type=radio]` with `name=tag`
and has `value` equal to `option_selected`.

Comment: @fawad You are **not** getting a correct `option_selected` variable then. Try `alert(option_selected);` to see what you are setting.

Comment: option_select variable is showing correct options by alert function

Comment: use `input:radio` to avoid a global DOM search for the selector.

Comment: See my answer here for details on the `input:radio` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165413/how-to-get-input-type-using-jquery/3165569#3165569

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio[name="tag"][value="' + option_selected + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @fawad: Does the content of `option_selected` correspond exactly to the `value` attributes of the radio buttons?

Comment: Yes exactly same value is there in the variable

Comment: Yes i did that but again when i press previous page button it does not select the option_select option :(

Comment: Something in your situation isn't what you think it is, then.  Try this fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/HEUt9/

Answer (score 0):

**You can try it!**

```
$('input:[name="tag"],[name="radio"],[value="' + option_selected + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Careful,  now.  You don't want to make your selector so complicated because it will cost a lot of overhead. Simple solution: add a class to each of the inputs and use that class as your selector. It'll look neater too.