# Accessing a jQuery Object in another object

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I´m trying to access a form element in the success callback of ajaxForm. The form element is passed as 4th element (see: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object -> success).

So if I test it via `console.log(form)`, it works. I get a jQuery Object and can access the form via `form[0].`

But the `console.log` shows me, that under `[0]` there are more elements, the inputs of the form. I can access them via `form[0][0] or form[0][1]` and so on.

But how can I get all child objects at once?

My situation is, that I don´t know the amount of inputs, so I need to access all inputs of the element through something like a `foreach`. But with `form[0]` I´m just getting the DOM-Element of the form.

It´s a bit complex, but I hope you understand my issue.

**Edit:**
This is what I get from console.log(form):

```
[form#doku_newrowJsonForm.doku_newrowJsonForm, context: form#doku_newrowJsonForm.doku_newrowJsonForm, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
0: form#doku_newrowJsonForm.doku_newrowJsonForm
 0: input
 1: input#AdrowAdtableId
 2: input#AdrowCustomerId
 3: input#AdrowContent19.input-small
 4: input#AdrowContent20.input-small
 5: input#AdrowContent21.input-small
 6: input#AdrowContent22.input-small
 7: input#AdrowContent23.input-small
 8: input#AdrowContent24.input-small
```

form[0] just gives me the DOM-Element and form[0].find(':input') gives me Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'find' ...

**Edit2**
To be clear: I want to get for example input#AdrowAdtableId. I can access this via form[0][1]. But I don´t know the lenght of inputs I have in the form. It´s dynamically. So it would be great, to do something like form[0].each(). But form[0] gives me the DOM Element and not the jQuery Object...

Comment: Be clear about the question..Elaborate it..

Comment: Please post the exact markup of the form (at least the start of it including one or two inputs) seeing that your question is a bit confusing at this juncture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `find()`. If you want all inputs inside the form (and the form itself can be accesses as `form[0]`) just do:

```
$(form[0]).find(":input")
```

If `form` if already a jQuery object the following is slightly better:

```
form.eq(0).find(":input")
```

Note that I used the `:input` pseudo-class to get all input-like elements, not just `<input>` ones.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, but it doesn´t work. Explanation below.

Comment: I´ve just edited my first post. Sorry for the delay... I get an Uncaught TypeError

Comment: My fault, but with console.log($(form[0]).find(':input') I get:

[prevObject: e.fn.init[1], context: form#doku_newrowJsonForm.doku_newrowJsonForm, selector: ":input", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]
context: form#doku_newrowJsonForm.doku_newrowJsonForm
length: 0

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery form and you're interested in the posted values, you could do the following:

```
var form = $('form');
form.ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
        form.data('form-values', arr);
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log(form.data('form-values')); // logs the submitted values
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access all the inputs on a form with the `.each()`

```
$(form[0]).find(':input').each(function{){
    var myInputValue = $(this).val();
});
```

If you need to know the specific type of input see this: [How to get input type using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165413/how-to-get-input-type-using-jquery/3165569#3165569)

Comment: Unfortunately $(form[0]).find... is not working. $(form[0]) returns exactly the same as `form` itself.