# How to select element except its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple table which looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="error">
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i click on `tr` i need to add custom class to it, but only whe i click on `tr`, not on the `input` inside it. How to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
table.find('tbody').on('click', 'tr:not(input)', function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('error');
    });
```

Comment: check for `e.target.tagName === 'INPUT'`, you may not want to register another eventon input just for this purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do here is check the node name to see if it is the td or the tr - or include other tags if you want.

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "td" || e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "tr") {
        $(this).toggleClass('error');
    }
});
```

If you specifically want the input excluded, you could then exclude those:

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(':input')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
table.find('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    if (e.target != this)
        return;    

    $(this).toggleClass('error');
});
```

Comment: Not a fan of negative conditionals, I would use `if (e.target === this) $(this).toggleClass('error');`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, wouldn't this stop execution if you click on the `td` elements nested under the `tr` elements? Or for instance if there was a `div` or `span` or `p` tag that you click on...

Comment: @Jasper You right, but OP said `but only when i click on tr`. Maybe he mentioned to `td`, so he can easily change from `tr` to `td`, but that's not the point. http://jsfiddle.net/tM59b/2/

Comment: `e.target != this` will always be true if the td exists and there is no space outside the td. - so nothing will ever get toggled.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the event from bubbling up to the `tr` element by using `event.stopPropagation`:

```
table.find("tr").on("click", function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("error");
}).find("input").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's some documentation for ya if you'd like to know more: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Here's a JSFiddle of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tM59b/1/

Comment: founded a better solution like `if (event.target.type != 'text')`

Comment: Use `if (event.target.tagName != "INPUT")` for a direct check. Not sure if there are other elements that have a `type` property that equals `text`.

Comment: `event.target.type` will not work for other input types like a radio, select etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165413/how-to-get-input-type-using-jquery/3165569#3165569 for discussion on input types.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener to the `input` and `return false;` from it to stop the event from propagating to the `tr`.

Like so:

```
$('tr input').click(function(e){
    return false;
});
```