# Stackoverflow's Animated Required Fields Validation Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am developing an ASP.NET website. Currently I am doing required field validations by simply adding a required field validater and Validation summary control at the top of the page. But I saw an interesting validation in stackoverflow.

When you click submit button its popup with a little animation.  I am guessing that it done by using jquery. I want that exact validation method. Whole validation thing with the shaking effect. I am not familiar with Jquery. Any resource will useful.

Thank you very much.

Here is the Link

https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Here is the screen shot

http://i62.tinypic.com/ofd4b4.jpg

Comment: Do you mean the shaking?

Comment: Yes Bram. Whole validation thing with the shaking effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165413/how-to-get-input-type-using-jquery) answer for form validation using jQuery

As for your actual question, the code below will do the job.
Check [the jsfiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/uwcxvmsh/) to see the results of the code below.

Note: In order for this to work, you must use the proper jQuery version. The version I am using for the fiddle is `jQuery 1.9.1` with `jQuery UI 1.9.2`

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="myTextID" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" />
    <div class="alert">
        <div class="alert-point"></div><span>No text was input</span>

        <div class="close">X</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select id="mySelectID">
        <option>Select something</option>
        <option>Some option</option>
        <option>Some other option</option>
    </select>
    <div class="alert">
        <div class="alert-point"></div><span>You must select an option. Note the first option is not a valid one</span>

        <div class="close">X</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input id="myButtonID" type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
<p>If no text is entered in the input box above and/or no selection is made (meaning the default selection is ignored) when the button is clicked, the error will show up</p>
```

The HTML is in a specific order:
Form includes all the elements necessary.
Input(or select, etc.) followed by div(with class of `.alert`).
The `<br/>` tags can be removed and CSS could be played with to make it prettier (in terms of code, layout and appearance), however I simply wanted to show the logic behind it all
The `div` tags with `class="alert"` have 3 sections.

1. Triangle (class `.alert-point`)
2. Alert message (in `span` tag)
3. X button to close the alert (I used a `div` tag for this as I thought it to be easiest)

The 3 inner components to the alert are all set to display `inline-block`

**CSS**

```
input, select {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.alert {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#C44D4D;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    font:13px arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:none;
    float:left;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:7px;
    margin-top:2px;
}
.alert-point {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #C44D4D;
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    top:0px;
}
.alert>span {
    line-height:24px;
}
.alert>.close {
    background-color:none;
    border:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    margin-left:10px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.submit {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

The CSS simply positions the elements using `float:left;` and `position:relative;`
The `div` tags with class `.alert` are set to `display:none;` and `opacity:0;` so that when the document loads, all the alerts are not visible (opacity set to 0 for animations in jQuery, default would otherwise be 1)
The rest of the CSS simply improves the appearance.

**JS**

```
$("#myButtonID").click(function () {
    var numShakes = 3; //full cycles
    var distance = 10; //in pixels
    var cycleSpeed = 1000; //in milliseconds
    if ($("#myTextID").val() === "") {
        $("#myTextID").next("div").css({
            display: "inline-block"
        });
        $("#myTextID").next("div").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).effect("shake", {
                direction: "left",
                times: numShakes,
                distance: distance
            }, cycleSpeed);
        });
    }
    if ($("#mySelectID")[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
        $("#mySelectID").next("div").css({
            display: "inline-block"
        });
        $("#mySelectID").next("div").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).effect("shake", {
                direction: "left",
                times: numShakes,
                distance: distance
            }, cycleSpeed);
        });
    }
});
$(".close").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

The jQuery code has 2 functions:

- Button click function (that processes the form validation)
- Div click function (that processes the close alert)

*Button click function*
This function declares 3 variables off the bat to be used in the shake function later. Play with these values as you wish. 
 - `numShakes` determines the number of times the shake effect will run
 - `distance` determines the distance in pixels that the object will move in the given direction (left to right is default)
 - `cycleSpeed` determines the speed of the shake effect

After these 3 variables are declared, each `if` statement represents a different input item. If you have more inputs, copy and paste the `if` statement, and then change what I mention later in that statement.

The `if` statement is structured like so:

1. The `if` statement determines if a value was input, selected, etc. So in the first `if` statement we get the value of the input with the id of `#myTextID` and if this is set to `""`, in other words, nothing was input, then do the following. This should work for any fields where input is based on keyboard input (in terms of text or numbers)
2. We then get the next `div` element that follows the `#myTextID` element in the DOM, which is of course our `div` with class `.alert`, and we change its CSS to `display:inline-block;` (this could be set to `block` as well if you'd like, I have it set to `inline-block` because I was testing things out and never changed it back. The reason we are doing this is so that the element now shows up in the document (but it is still invisible - `opacity:0` in the CSS document)
3. We now grab that same item and we use the animate function to set its `opacity` to `1` after `500` milliseconds.
4. After the `500` milliseconds is up, we run our animation end function which is set to our shake function. This function grabs the same item we've been working with and uses the effect method. From the effect method, we are using the `"shake"` effect. We also plug in those variables we declared at the beginning of the click function
5. Repeat for all your inputs changing, as I mentioned earlier I would mention, the id of the items (there are 3 ids to change per `if` statement). You should also make sure that you're searching for the proper "0 input" value (meaning that the user hasn't yet input a value into the required field). As we can see the second `if` statement uses a different condition than the first one. The link I provided above should help you with what to check for form validation

Finally, the div click function, which closes the alert. This function simply animates the opacity back down to 0 and following this animation (once the animation has been completed), we set its display back to `"none"`

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT - Added explanations below each section of code**

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ctwheels. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You're very welcome. I tested for newer jQuery versions, it also works with version `jQuery 2.0.2` with `jQuery UI 1.10.3`. If you'd like an explanation of the code I'm more than willing to add one if you'd like?

Comment: Yes I really appreciate if you can ctwheels. It will be useful for others too.

Comment: @user3769650 I have added an explanation for the code now, let me know if there is anything else or if it is too confusing, I'm very tired (almost 5am here, don't know why I'm not asleep yet) so it may be a little jumbled

Answer (score 1):

In you validation function when you show your message you can use [`jQuery UI shake effect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/)

Code:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $("#toggle").effect("shake");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p8xx3t2f/