# php how to get the type of form fields using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

> I want get the name , value and type of the fields in the form. I am using the following code which helped me to get the name and value but type = "text" always even for checkboxs and radio button too. i want get the exact types of the fields whether it is checkbox, radio or text. 
>   here is the code

```
 <form action="">
   <h1> Try Form</h1>
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="khan"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="wazir"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked"> I have a car<br>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other 
</form>
<button>Serialize form values</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

> Here is the script

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
            $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " :" + $( "input" ).attr( "type" ) + " ");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get input type using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165413/how-to-get-input-type-using-jquery)

Comment: yes i have gone through this question but didn't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$( "input" ).attr( "type" )
```

to

```
$( "input[name='" + field.name + "']" ).attr( "type" )
```

you must pick specify input to get type correct

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through `input` element and get `prop('type')` to get the input type:

`prop()` is a JQuery function that gives you the properties of an element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var x = $("form").serializeArray();
    $('input').each(function() {
      $("#results").append($(this).val() + " :" + $(this).prop('type') + "<br />");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <h1> Try Form</h1>
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="khan"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="wazir"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked"> I have a car<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
<button>Serialize form values</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $("form").find("input");
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
            $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " :" + field.type);
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ananth_2353/gan6hx6r/)

Comment: Did you add jquery plugin in your page? Also check 'x' value in your code.

Comment: look at my script I have used this. field.type = undefined.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle?