# Event triggered on any modification on my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a form with an imput text and a select.
To submit the form i want the user to click a verify button in order to check if all fields are correctly filed.
If it is then the button submit who was initialy disabled is now enable.

Here is the problem, i'd like that if the user modify anything in the form again then the button turn back to disable so that he must verify again to submit.

To do so i'd like to find a jQuery event that triggers on any event on my form to turn back the submit button to disable again.

Any idea of how could i do ?

Comment: Jquery has a chaange event you can add to a form that will bubble up events form the inputs $('#formId').change(function(){...}); Also, this functionality is generally done with one button. Cancel the form submit and submit through javascript if validation passes

Comment: Oh thanks i didn't know about that event !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the event with the on Change function of jQuery. You have to assign it to every input field / Select or whatever, or give them all the same class.
Here is a [Doc](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Example:

```
<form>
    <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
    <select class="target">
        <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="other">
    Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Script:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

If you provide any sample Code, we'd be able to help you even more.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know that the change event could be applyied to a form ! It works !

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the form (delegateTarget) then from that select the input types (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3165569/125981) that you wish to be in scope to attach event hanlders, and disable those desired by there type.  Since it IS possible to have multiple I have included and example with two submit buttons that are and a reset button that is NOT disabled.  To reverse that, you would need to have some way to clear them out so I added an example of a custom event.

Added a reset event handler since it may come into play here.

```js
$('#myform').on('change keyup', 'input[type="text"], select', function(event) {
    $(event.delegateTarget).find('input[type="submit"]').each(function() {
      console.log("disable:", this);
      this.disabled = true;
    });
  })
  .on('all-clear', function(event) {
    $(event.delegateTarget).find('input[type="submit"]').each(function() {
      this.disabled = false;
    });
  })
  .on('click', '#allclear', function(event) {
    $(event.delegateTarget).trigger('all-clear');
  })
  .on('reset', function(event){
      // do whatever is desired on the reset of the form
  });
  .find('input[type="text"]').trigger('change'); //IF you want disabled initially
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" value="text stuff" />
  <select>
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">First Option</option>
    <option value="option2">Another Option</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="submit" value="Possible Submit" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  <button id="allclear" type="button">All clear</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is really better answer than the accepted one. Only one event listener is used here.