# Why is input field.type returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input element:

```
<input type="password" name="password1" autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" disabled class="register_field" required id="id_password1">
```

When I assign it to a variable and log its type:

```
const password1 = $("#id_password1");
console.log(password1.type);
```

It returns 'undefined'. Why not password?

I thought it may have been the initial disabled property on the input, or the novalidate property of the form itself, or because I'm using Django's template engine to generate the form, but none were the cause. Immense thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165413/how-to-get-input-type-using-jquery/3165569#3165569

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, `$(...)` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element. In that case you want to call `.attr('type')`.

```js
console.log($('#field').attr('type'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="field">
```